# Network Formation and Large Array's in Matlab Optimization

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory

I am getting an error using repmat. My Matlab version is 2017a. "Requested 3711450x2726 (75.4GB) array exceeds maximum array size..." First, some context.

I have an adjacency matrix of social network data call it D. D is 2725x2725 with 1s denoting a link between agents i and j and 0s otherwise. I have been provided a function and sub-functions for a network formation model. There are K regressors (x variables). The model requires forming a dyad-specific regressor matrix W that is W = 0.5N(N-1) x K. In my data, this is 3711450 x K. For a start, I select only one x variable so K=1.

In the main function, there are two steps. The first step calculates the joint MLE from a logit. I have a problem in the second step computation of the variance covariance matrix with array size. Inside this step, there is a calculation that creates a 3711450 x n (2725) matrix using repmat.

```
  INFO        = ((repmat((exp_Xbeta ./ (1+exp_Xbeta).^2),1,K) .* X)'*X);
```

exp_Xbeta is 3711450 x K and X is a sparse 3711450 x 2725 matrix with Bytes = 178171416 of class double. The error occurs at INFO.

I've tried converting X to a tall matrix but thus far no joy. I've tried adding sparse to the INFO line but again no joy. Anyone have any ideas short of going to a cluster or getting more ram? Could I somehow convert X from a sparse matrix to a full matrix inside a datastore and then call the datastore using tall? I have not been able to figure out how to do that if it is possible.

Once INFO is constructed as an array it will be used later in one of the sub-functions. So, it needs to be callable. In case you're curious, INFO is the second derivative matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that producing the INFO matrix all at once was too much for my memory constraints. I split up the steps, but still, repmat and subsequent steps were a problem. Now, I've turned to building up the INFO matrix one step at a time, while never holding more than exp_Xbeta, X, and two vectors in memory. Replacing the construction of INFO with

```
   for i = 1:d
    s1_i = step1(:,1).*X(:,i);
    s1_i = s1_i'; 
    for j = 1:d;
        INFO(i,j) = s1_i*X(:,j);
    end
    clear s1_i;
end
```

has dropped the memory requirement, though its slow, and things seem to be working. For anyone interested, below is a little example illustrating the point.

```
clear all

N = 20
n = 0.5*N*(N-1)
exp_Xbeta = rand(n,1);
X         = rand(n,N); 

step1     = (exp_Xbeta ./ (1+exp_Xbeta).^2);
[c,d]     = size(X);
INFO      = zeros(d,d);

for i = 1:d
    s1_i = step1(:,1).*X(:,i)
    s1_i = s1_i' 
    for j = 1:d
        INFO(i,j) = s1_i*X(:,j)
    end
    clear s1_i
end

K = 1
INFO2  = ((repmat((exp_Xbeta ./ (1+exp_Xbeta).^2),1,K) .* X)'*X);

% Methods produce equivalent matrices
INFO
INFO2
```